# QtSQL reading special characters

Tags: qt, encoding, utf-8, sqlite, character-encoding

I have a Database which stores strings with Portuguese characters such as é, ç, ã.

I edit the file with the INSERT queries on Notepad++ with UTF-8 set as encoding. I also insert on the sqlite3 database after 'PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8"' is set.

Now, when I try reading it on my Qt application, the query returns invalid characters. I do a query such as:

```
QSqlQuery query;
QString description;

query.prepare("SELECT * FROM Training");
query.exec();

while(query.next())
{
    description = query.record().field("description").value().toString().toUtf8();
    ...
}
```

I have already tried without 'toUtf8()', and with 'toLatin1()'. None of those worked. I get only question marks or garbage.

EDIT:
When I SELECT directly from sqlite3 command-line the strings are printted correctly!

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @CL Windows 7. I thought the Notepad++ reference made this clear :)

Comment: I though the Qt SQLite3 DB driver performed automatic encoding conversion on strings anyway, are you _sure_ you need to do anything with the returned `QString`?  Even if it didn't, it seems odd to me to pull out UTF-8 data from the DB and then call `toUtf8()` on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `sqlite3` in the Windows console, UTF-8 characters are not handled correctly.

To enter and display UTF-8 characters correctly, you have to use any other tool.

Comment: I always thinking that was the reason as well. I am now using SQLiteStudio to insert those rows, and everything went fine!